# I can't understand why the command 'typedef' can be used like this

Tags: c, function, pointers, typedef

I was studying C99 - Function pointer part and my textbook offered a way to use 'typedef' for  simplifying the code below :

```
int (*p[4])(int,int) = {&Sum,&Sub,&Mul,&Div};
```

↓

```
typedef int (*OP_TYPE)(int,int);
OP_TYPE p[4]={&Sum,&Sub,&Mul,&Div};
```

I've known that 'typedef' can be used only like this :
eg.

```
typedef unsigned short int US;
```

Was it not wrong, `int` would be altered as `(*OP_TYPE)(int,int)`, and Isn't it right the second sentence become `(*OP_TYPE)(int,int)(*p[4])(int,int) = {&Sum,&Sub,&Mul,&Div};`

I can't understand why the second sentence could be like that.

Comment: That is the way to define a function pointer type in C. See more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work.

Answer (score 3):

The `typedef` keyword behaves grammatically like storage modifiers (i.e. `auto`, `register`, `static` etc) except the initialization part. My guess the reason for that is that the early versions of C compilers shared code between variable declaration and type alias declarations.

Therefore the type alias declaration and variable declaration look more or less the same:

```
static  int (*A[4])(int,int); // staic variable
typedef int (*B[4])(int,int); // type alias
        int (*C[4])(int,int); // local variable
```

I guess the question is why one cannot do:

```
int (*[4])(int,int) C;
```

I have no good answer to that, C grammar is simply defined this this way. I can guess that without the anchor the compiler cannot correctly parse the type.

So why one can't do:

```
(int (*[4])(int,int)) C;
```

Answer:

It would solve the problem with missing anchor. However, it cannot be used because it will conflict with cast operator `(type) expr`. Note that symbol `C` may be defined on out scope resulting in ambiguity.

```
int C;
{
  // cast `C` to `int*` or maybe declare a pointer to `int`
  (int*)C;
}
```

However, there is a workaround with `typeof` extension (a feature in upcoming C23).

```
typeof(int (*[4])(int,int)) C;
```

This is more or less the same how the compiler expands the following declaration:

```
typedef int (*OP_TYPE)(int,int);
OP_TYPE p[4]={&Sum,&Sub,&Mul,&Div};

  to

typeof(int(*)(int,int)) p[4] = { ... }
```

Moreover, using this trick allows a neat and readable declaration of complex types.

```
typeof(int(int,int))* p[4] = { .... }
```

It is easy to see that `p` is a 4-element array of pointers to `int(int,int)` function.

Answer (score 1):

> Was it not wrong, `int` would be altered as `(*OP_TYPE)(int,int)`, and Isn't it right the second sentence become `(*OP_TYPE)(int,int)(*p[4])(int,int) = {&Sum,&Sub,&Mul,&Div};`

The declaration

```
typedef int (*OP_TYPE)(int, int);
```

does not change the meaning of `int` - it changes the meaning of `OP_TYPE`.

First, some background:

Declarations in C are broken into two main sections: a sequence of *declaration specifiers*, followed by a comma-separated list of *declarators*.

The declarator introduces the name of the thing being declared, along with information about that thing's array-ness, function-ness, and pointer-ness.  In a typedef, that name becomes an alias for the type.

The structure of the declarator is meant to mirror the structure of an expression in the code.  For example, suppose you have an array `arr` of pointers to `int` and you want to access the integer object pointed to by the `i`’th element; you’d index into the array and dereference the result, like so:

```
printf( "%d\n", *arr[i] ); // *arr[i] is parsed as *(arr[i])
```

The type of the *expression* `*arr[i]` is `int`; that's why we write its declaration as

```
int *arr[N];
```

instead of

```
int *[N] arr;
```

In the expression, the operand of the postfix `[]` subscript operator is `arr`, and the operand of the unary `*` dereference operator is the expression `arr[i]`.  Those operators follow the same rules of precedence in a declaration, hence the structure of the declaration above.

The declaration reads as

```
     arr      -- arr
     arr[N]   -- is an array of
    *arr[N]   --   pointer to
int *arr[N];  --     int
```

Thus, object named `arr` has type "array of pointer to `int`";

Similarly, if you have an array of function pointers and you want to call one of those functions, you’d index into the array, dereference the result, and then call the resulting function with whatever arguments:

```
x = (*p[i])(a, b);
```

Again, the type of the *expression* `(*p[i])(a, b)` is `int`, so it follows that the declaration of `p` is written

```
int (*p[4])(int, int);
```

and not

```
int (*[4])(int, int) p;
```

Again, the declaration reads as

```
      p                  -- p
      p[4]               -- is a 4-element array of
     *p[4]               --   pointer to
    (*p[4])(        )    --     function taking
    (*p[4])(   ,    )    --       unnamed parameter
    (*p[4])(int,    )    --       is an int
    (*p[4])(int,    )    --       unnamed parameter
    (*p[4])(int, int)    --       is an int
int (*p[4])(int, int);   --     returning int
```

so the *object* named `p` has the type "array pointer to function taking two `int` parameters and returning `int`".

Clear so far?

So, how does `typedef` affect this?

Let's start with a declaration *without* the `typedef`:

```
int (*OP_TYPE)(int, int);
```

This declares `OP_TYPE` as an *object* of type "pointer to function taking two `int` parameters and returning `int`".  If we add the `typedef` keyword:

```
typedef int (*OP_TYPE)(int, int);
```

it changes the meaning of the declaration such that `OP_TYPE` is an *alias* for the type "pointer to function taking two `int` parameters and returning `int`".  It doesn't change the *structure* of the declaration at all, only the meaning.  Thus, you can write

```
OP_TYPE fp;
```

and it will mean exactly the same thing as

```
int (*fp)(int, int);
```

Some other examples may help drive the concept home; going back to the earlier examples, if

```
int *ap[N];
```

declares `ap` as an *object* of type "4-element array of pointer to `int`", then

```
typedef int *ap[N];
```

declares `ap` as an *alias* for the type "4-element array of pointer to `int`", such that

```
ap foo;
```

is equivalent to

```
int *foo[N];
```

If

```
int (*blah)[N];
```

declares `blah` as an object of type "pointer to N-element array of `int`", then the declaration

```
typedef int (*blah)[N];
```

declares `blah` as an alias for the type "pointer to N-element array of `int`".

In the example you provide,

```
unsigned short int US;
```

declares `US` as object of type `unsigned short int`; thus,

```
typedef unsigned short int US;
```

declares `US` as an alias for the type `unsigned short int`.

Declarations (and thus `typedefs`) can get arbitrarily complex:

```
int *(*(*foo())[N])(double);
```

`foo` is a pointer to a function that returns a pointer to an array of pointers to functions taking a `double` parameter and returning a pointer to `int`.  Adding a `typedef`:

```
typedef int *(*(*foo())[N])(double);
```

changes `foo` to be an alias for the type "function returning a pointer to an array of pointers to functions taking a `double` parameter and returning a pointer to `int`; again,

```
foo bar;
```

is equivalent to writing

```
int *(*(*bar())[N])(double);
```

Comment: [Cdecl](https://cdecl.org/) doesn't like your declaration. I think you meant `int *(*(*(*foo)())[])(double )` which can be generated using `declare foo as pointer to function returning pointer to array of pointer to function (double) returning pointer to int`

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica - it doesn't like the `N` for the array size - if I replace it with a numeric literal it works - `explain int *(*(*foo())[10])(double)`, which yields "declare foo as function returning pointer to array 10 of pointer to function (double) returning pointer to int".

Comment: Sorry, what I wrote was very unclear. Yes, the N was a problem, but I simply removed it. What I really wanted to say is that your code does not match the description you gave. Your declaration has 3 `*`, mine has 4. That's because you wrote that "`foo` is *a pointer to* a function that [...]" but you probably meant "`foo` is a function that [...]". I assumed the text was correct and the code wrong, but now I understand it's the other way around. Anyway... Doesn't matter. This answer is great, and it's the only one that understood what the OP misunderstood about typedef. You have my +1.

Answer (score 0):

`int` is not "altered" by a `typedef`. `typedef unsigned short int US;` is not "altering" `unsigned short int`, it is defining the identifier `US` to denote the same type as `unsigned short int`. Likewise, `typedef int (*OP_TYPE)(int,int)` is defining the identifier `OP_TYPE` to denote the same type as `int (*)(int, int)` (a pointer to a function returning `int` with parameter type list `int, int`).

Syntactically, `typedef` is like a storage class specifier but it defines a "typedef name" instead of declaring a variable.  Compare `typedef int (*OP_TYPE)(int, int);` to `static int (*op)(int, int);`. `OP_TYPE` is a typedef name and `op` is a variable. `OP_TYPE` and `op` both have the same type `int (*)(int, int)`. `OP_TYPE` can be used as a type in subsequent declarations, so that `static OP_TYPE op;` is equivalent to `static int (*op)(int, int);`

Answer (score 0):

OP_TYPE is a function pointer type.  Here is an example:

```
// This is a function
// It has a single parameter and returns
// an int
int some_func(int a) {
  return(a+1);
}

int main(void) {

  // regular usage of the function
  printf("some_func(1) = %d\n", some_func(1));

  // fun_ptr is a function pointer
  // that points to the function some_func
  int (*fun_ptr)(int) = &some_func;
  printf("via fun_ptr->some_func(2) = %d\n", fun_ptr(2));

  // create the typedef
  typedef int (*funptr_type)(int);
  // usage of typedef
  funptr_type another_func_ptr = &some_func;
  // usage of function pointer via typedef
  printf("via typedef some_func(3) = %d\n", another_func_ptr(3));

  return(0);

}
```

Usage

```
some_func(1) = 2
via fun_ptr->some_func(2) = 3
via typedef some_func(3) = 4
```